# Pass url parameters from a page to use them later on Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, url, woocommerce, parameters

How can I pass URL parameters from a page in WordPress so I can use them later with woocommerce actions?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of function that will grab your URL parameter in php sessions (you will have to replace in the code `custom_key` by your desired query var:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'store_url_params' );
function store_url_params() {
    if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
        session_start();
    }
    if (isset($_GET['custom_key'])) {
        // Store the value in a cookie
        $_SESSION['custom_key'] = esc_attr($_GET['custom_key']);
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (active theme).

Then you will call the value later using:

```
$value = $_SESSION['custom_key'];
```